# How do I match everything after the first word?

Tags: regex

So I'm a total regex n00b and I have a google spreadsheet with a column that contains names.

I figured out how to match the first word, so I was able to create a column containing only the first names.

Now I want a column that contains the middle and last names (combined). So I figured I need the regex code to match everything after the first word. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you add the regex you wrote for accessing firstname and add some samples and expected vs current output?

Comment: https://rubular.com/r/rJtPbvUEwx @Julian

Comment: This is the regex I used to get the first word: ^([\w\-]+)

Comment: Here is the google sheets formula I used: =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"^([\w\-]+)"))

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what language you are using it can be slightly different but for example if you are using python you could simply use:

`(?P<firstName>^\w+)\s(?P<middleAndLast>.+)`

[example](https://regex101.com/r/9CFSwV/1); Which would grab the first name and then the second group would just be everything after. If the column in your data set has more text in it we can make it more complicated.

For [example](https://regex101.com/r/9CFSwV/4) you could add in descriptions for both the middle and last name with the optional look ahead for the middle name`(?=...)` for the middle group incase someone doesn't have a middle name. This would check for a middle name or just grab the last name. You can remove the `$` if the last name is not the end of the entire string.

which would look something like:
`(?P<firstName>^\w+)\s((?P<middle>[\w\.]+)(?=\s\w))?(\s?(?P<Last>\w+))$`

Here is a [ruby example](https://rubular.com/r/aWSf9n2EixaplV) that grabs the first name and then all the white space and characters after it.

For google sheets something like the following should work:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(F3,"(^\w+)\s(\w.*)")`

Helpful resource [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for responding. What you are saying goes a bit above my head, probably because of the python. The regex I used to get the first word was: ^([\w\-]+)

I just need something that excludes the first word and gets the rest.

Comment: BTW I'm not using python, just a a normal spreadsheet in google (same as excel)

Comment: @Julian Please see the update to my answer. You can also refer to the documentation I linked. Hopefully it helps. Basically make two groups separated by a space `\s`.